# where is the name property in a non visual user control

Tags: c#, properties, user-controls

I have a user control inherited from Component

```
public partial class myDataTable : Component
```

In a method from this user control, I need the name of the component, but the name property is not there ????

example

```
string something = "whatever " + this.Name + " more whatever";
```

But I get error message : MyDataTable does not contain a definition for 'Name' ...
In the form where the control is dropped on, there is a Name property, so why is this name property not available in my code ?

here is a stripped version of the component

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace gttControls
{
public partial class gttDataTable : Component
{
    private string designerFile = "";


    public string DesignerFile
    { 
        get { return designerFile; }
        set
        {
            designerFile = value;

    // do something with this file here
    string something = "whatever " + this.Name + " more whatever";
    // more something here
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the Component?

Comment: edit the question so it contains a stripped version of the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms, `Name` is property of `Control`, not `Component` class.

And your class (by the way - it is not `UserControl` as it is not inherited from `UserControl`) is not inherited from `Control` - only from `Component` - so it has no `Name` property.

`Form` class is inherited from `Control` (indirectly, by some levels of inheritance) - so `Form` has `Name` property.

**EDIT**
Probably you was confused by designer showed something like this:
[image]

But note - that `(Name)` is actually not a `Name` property of class. Just have a look at brackets around it.

Comment: So why does the designer in visual studio shows a name property for it which I can even change ?

Comment: The person who invented this is fired I hope... Why would anyone implement the name property a such a late level like control, while this should be the only property that should be available at every component, control, whatever... This makes no sense at all